# How to send a request like in terminal in react?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, request

I'm trying to send the following request in my react application

```
curl -H 'Client-ID: p0gch4mp101fy451do9uod1s1x9i4a' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?game_id=33214'
```

I am able to put this exact string into my terminal and receive a response, but how exactly do I go about doing this in JavaScript or REACT?

I have tried using fetch in react but that only allows me to send a get request and that gives me an response of unauthorized access because it only takes a link, and if I send the entire thing as a string it'll just give me a 404 error because it's unrecognized.

In my terminal I can just paste in the whole string and get a valid response back. how do I replicate this in JavaScript or react?

Comment: You can use Axios. Add appropriate request headers otherwise you will keep getting Unauthorized. Honestly, Fetch should work if you add the Header I see in your CURL command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch works with any standard request method and allows for setting headers as below:

```
const url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?game_id=33214';
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Client-ID': 'p0gch4mp101fy451do9uod1s1x9i4a'
  },
  //body: JSON.stringify({name:'test'}) //example of how to have a body also
};

fetch(url, options)
.then(res=>{
  if(!res.ok)
    throw new Error(res.statusText);
  return res.json();
})
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Request failed', err)
});
```

for more info read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API 
or check this https://flaviocopes.com/fetch-api/

Comment: Please remember to use polyfill if your app should work in IE (for example: https://github.com/github/fetch)